# IDO complete filename on `insert-file`

Tags: emacs, ido

Is it possible to have ido provide the same functionality for `insert-file` as it does for `find-file`, i.e. the filename completion?

I've tried to find a corresponding variable setting but had no luck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ido-insert-file` is to `insert-file` what `ido-find-file` is to `find-file`. `ido-insert-file` is bound to <kbd>C-x i</kbd> when `ido-mode`'s file behavior is enabled:

```
(ido-mode 'files) ; turn on ido file behavior only (finding, writing, inserting, ...)
```

or

```
(ido-mode t) ; turn on both ido buffer and file behavior
```

From `ido-mode`'s docstring,

> **`(ido-mode &optional ARG)`**
>
> Toggle ido speed-ups on or off.
>
> With ARG, turn ido speed-up on if arg is positive, off otherwise. Turning on ido-mode will remap (via a minor-mode keymap) the default keybindings for the `find-file` and `switch-to-buffer` families of commands to the ido versions of these functions.
>
> However, if ARG arg equals `'files`, remap only commands for files, or if it equals `'buffers`, remap only commands for buffer switching.